# UIScrollView Subviews being misplaced when scaled down and Subviews not showing up when rounded

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

so I'm making my first Swift iOS app. I have two problems that I would like some help with.

**First problem**: I'm running into some issues with subviews that I created programmatically not being aligned properly when displayed on a small screen.

This first picture shows how I intend the scrollview to look. (iPhone 11 Pro Max)

[image: How the scrollview is supposed to look]

However, this is what it looks like when it's on a smaller screen. (iPhone 8)

[image: Subviews are cut off on this picture]

I think the issue is with me creating the subviews programmatically as the scrollview's size is what I want it to be.

Here's the swift code that I used inside `viewDidLoad()`:

```
var districtNewsSize = 10;
var districtNewsFrame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0);
// District News -----
        districtNewsPageControl.numberOfPages = districtNewsSize;
        for aIndex in 0..<districtNewsSize{
            districtNewsFrame.origin.x = districtNewsScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(aIndex);
            districtNewsFrame.size = districtNewsScrollView.frame.size;


            // create content in scrollview
            let contentView = UIButton(frame: districtNewsFrame);
            contentView.backgroundColor = makeColor(r: 147, g: 66, b: 78);
            contentView.setTitle("titletext", for: .normal);
            contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20; // just to show how displaced the views are


            // add contentview to scrollview
            self.districtNewsScrollView.addSubview(contentView);
        }
        // change horizontal size of scrollview
        districtNewsScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: districtNewsScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(districtNewsSize), height: districtNewsScrollView.frame.size.height);
        districtNewsScrollView.delegate = self;
```

**Second Problem**: When attempting to round the top two corners of the scrollview, the content inside the scrollview seems to disappear.

This is a picture of the first subview.

[image: First subview seems fine]

This is a picture of the second subview.

[image: The second subview doesn't even show anymore]

I also have a suspicion that this is caused by my function that I am using to round the top edges.

Here's the extension function I made for UIScrollView:

```
extension UIScrollView{
    func setRoundedEdge(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat){ // label.setRoundedEdge([.TopLeft, . TopRight], radius: 10)
        let maskPath1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: corners,
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPath1.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer1
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling the function in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
districtNewsScrollView.setRoundedEdge(corners: [.topRight,.topLeft], radius: 30);
```

***Any help will greatly be appreciated. I've been stuck on these two problems and can't find anything online (probably because I'm not wording it right but I don't know how to describe these issues). Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix both issues:

````
// District News -----
        districtNewsFrame.size = districtNewsScrollView.frame.size;
        districtNewsFrame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 34;
        for aIndex in 0..<districtNewsSize{
            //districtNewsFrame.origin.x = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-52) * CGFloat(aIndex);
            //districtNewsFrame.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size;
            districtNewsFrame.origin.x = (districtNewsFrame.size.width * CGFloat(aIndex));

            // create content in scrollview
            let contentView = UIButton(frame: districtNewsFrame); // wrapper for article
            //testButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ahsldpi.png"), for: .normal);
            contentView.backgroundColor = makeColor(r: 147, g: 66, b: 78);

            // content inside contentView -------
            let articleContentFrame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:districtNewsFrame.width,height:districtNewsFrame.height-60);
            let articleContent = UIView(frame: articleContentFrame); // may be image?
            articleContent.backgroundColor = makeColor(r: 138, g: 138, b: 138);

            let articleLabelFrame = CGRect(x:0,y:districtNewsFrame.height-60,width:districtNewsFrame.width,height:60);
            let articleLabel = UILabel(frame: articleLabelFrame);
            articleLabel.text = "    " + "Title";
            articleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
            articleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "DINCondensed-Bold", size: 30);



            // add content inside contentView to contentview
            contentView.addSubview(articleContent);
            contentView.addSubview(articleLabel);
            // add contentview to scrollview
            contentView.setRoundedEdge(corners: [.topRight,.topLeft,.bottomLeft,.bottomRight], radius: 30);
            self.districtNewsScrollView.addSubview(contentView);
        }
        // change horizontal size of scrollview
        districtNewsScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (districtNewsFrame.size.width * CGFloat(districtNewsSize)), height: districtNewsScrollView.frame.size.height);
        districtNewsScrollView.delegate = self;
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using storyboard for scrollview and programmatically adding subviews in viewDidLoad,

```
districtNewsFrame.origin.x = districtNewsScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(aIndex);
districtNewsFrame.size = districtNewsScrollView.frame.size;
```

Should be changed to

```
districtNewsFrame.origin.x = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(aIndex);
districtNewsFrame.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.frame.size;
```

Use screen's size on viewDidLoad since the views in storyboards are loaded but constraints in auto layout is not yet applied.

For second question,

change extension to

```
extension UIScrollView{
    func setRoundedEdge(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat){ // label.setRoundedEdge([.TopLeft, . TopRight], radius: 10)
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

and view controller to

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();
    districtNewsScrollView.setRoundedEdge(corners: [.topRight,.topLeft], radius: 30);
}
```

Comment: These two things didn't work.
***First problem:*** your code: ```districtNewsFrame.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.frame.size;```, but ```bounds.frame``` doesn't exist. I tried ```districtNewsFrame.origin.x = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) * CGFloat(aIndex);

districtNewsFrame.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size;``` but it also didn't work.

Comment: ***Second Problem***: the same issue is persisting even after using your code. Thanks